# How to use services created in WSO2 Governance Registry?

Tags: registry

In WSO2 Governance Registry, I created Services.
 (Main -> Metadata -> Add -> Service)
And successfully created it.

Now, in which component(ex. ESB etc) I can ref it?
And what is the purpose of WSO2 Governance Registry Service?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 governance registry is not a service hosting product. It is a meta data repository.
You can store the service meta data like WSDL, Schema, Policies .. etc and access those resources through the ESB. The benefit of storing those meta data in Registry is you can govern using life cycle management and versioning.

Thanks
Ajith